# When should we have main() in python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, program-entry-point

I see many python scripts having the following `main()` code pattern below;

```
def main():
    print("Hello World!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, I have written many python scripts which do not have `main()` and I do not experience any problems without `main()`. When should one use `main()` in a python script, given that not having it seems to have no detrimental effect?

I am using python 3.8

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Check this [article](https://realpython.com/python-main-function/) it may be helpful.